# Spring cloud config using ssh instead of https

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am banging my head around why spring cloud config is using ssh even when i try to provide https uri in the application.yaml. Here's my quick config file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/myOrg/myRepo
          skipSslValidation: true
          username: ${GITHUB_USERNAME}
          password: ${GITHUB_PASSWORD}

server:
  port: 8888
  ssl:
    enabled: false
```

I would assume spring cloud config to use https to do this connection and clone the repo. Can someone help me understand why still it uses `ssh` and fails on auth(which is obvious as I don't provide any private key):

```
org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchRepositoryException: Cannot clone or checkout repository: https://github.com/myOrg/myRepo
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment...
    
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: git@github.com:myOrg/myRepo: Auth fail
    ....

Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:519) ~[jsch-0.1.55.jar:na]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:115) ~[org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch-5.12.0.202106070339-r.jar:5.12.0.202106070339-r]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

My suspicion is that if https doesn't work, it tries via ssh. That's why it's using ssh. Has anyone faced issues like this?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Apparently, the fallback was due to the `~/.git` folder in which ssh access was recommended. Deleting it solved the problem.